# Hide Row if Cell is blank

Tags: excel, vba, show-hide

I have a worksheet active code that hides all rows if the contents of column `A:A` is blank. Now, this code works fine. I am trying to apply this same code to a button on the same sheet which will then hide any rows in Column `M:M` that is also blank.

```
Sub Hide_Unused_Rows()

'Hide rows with no requirements
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim datasheet As Worksheet
Dim i As Long

Set datasheet = Sheets("ORDER FORM")

lastrow = datasheet.Range("M" & datasheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = lastrow To 2 Step -1
    If datasheet.Cells(i, 1) = "" Then
        datasheet.Rows(i & ":" & i).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
Next I

End Sub
```

As mentioned above this code works perfectly when it is applied to phase 1 (Worksheet activate) but when applied to phase 2 it doesn't hide the rows where cells in column `M` are blank. The code for the 2 actions is the same with the exception that `lastrow = datasheet.Range("M" & datasheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` reference either Column `A` or Column `M`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgott to change the column here:

```
If datasheet.Cells(i, 1) = "" Then
```

See below.

```
Sub Hide_Unused_Rows()

'Hide rows with no requirements
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim datasheet As Worksheet
Dim i As Long

Set datasheet = Sheets("ORDER FORM")

lastrow = datasheet.Range("M" & datasheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = lastrow To 2 Step -1
    If datasheet.Cells(i, "M") = "" Then
        datasheet.Rows(i & ":" & i).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much... works great blows my mind that had no problem building the code but 1 simple oversite has caused me hours of annoyance

Comment: You could also parameterise the procedure.  Update your sub heading to `Sub HideUnused_Rows(Col As String)`, update the last row line to `lastrow = datasheet.Range(Col & datasheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`.  Now create two new subs called `HideA()` and `HideM()` add this code to `HideA()` - `HideUnused_Rows "A"` and similar for `HideM()` - attach these subs to your two buttons.